# How to get the total found rows without considering the limit in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I found it very unprofessional to make a secondary query to check for more results in order to display a *load more* button.

I'm using PDO, is there any way to get the total found rows without the limit filter but still filtering the results?

Current Code:

```
// Show Results

$start = 0

$r=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE area=:area LIMIT $start,10");
$r->execute($fields);

// See if there is more results

$r=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE area=:area");
$r->execute($fields);

$offset=$start+10;
if($r->rowCount() > $offset){
echo "<div class='load'>Load More</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MySQL only AFAIK:

```
$r=$db->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM locations WHERE area=:area LIMIT $start,10");
$r->execute($fields);

var_dump($r->fetchAll());

var_dump($db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS();')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));
```

About as heavy for the database server as querying a single time for all the records of course. For non-MySQL use, this query is of course better then getting the rowcount of *all* the records:

```
$r=$db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM locations WHERE area=:area");
$r->execute($fields);
$count = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
echo $count;
```

Comment: Some say using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is up to 10x slower than running two queries, depending on indexes and other conditions. Read and test before using, is my advice. Check the performance test here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: yes, people should test. However, as that article is about 8 years old, I wouldn't trust the content of that article either ;)