# help with counting mysql results

Tags: php, mysql

I have to modify an existing PHP script so that it displays the total number of matches in the database before it shows the results for the current page. The query is:

```
SELECT products.features, products.make_id, products.model, products.price,
       products.id, brands.name AS brandname, brands.id AS brandid
FROM products
LEFT JOIN brands ON products.make_id=brands.id
WHERE products.active=1 AND brands.active=1 AND (products.category=22)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,12
```

How do I get the number of results? mysql_num_rows() obviously returns 12 but I don't know how to use count in this query, everything I try returns some error.

I could just execute the query once without the limit (clause?) but that seems a bit inefficient.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Why can you not use `mysql_num_rows()`?

Comment: Because it returns 12 rows because limit is set to 12 (or whatever the desired number of results per page is)

Comment: I see. I'll fetch a duplicate, hang on...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the total found rows without considering the limit in PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596155/how-to-get-the-total-found-rows-without-considering-the-limit-in-pdo)

Comment: considering "per page" sounds a lot like pagination, I added some reading material if you're truly worried about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MySQL function [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT
>   clause to restrict the number of rows
>   the server returns to the client. In
>   some cases, it is desirable to know
>   how many rows the statement would have
>   returned without the LIMIT, but
>   without running the statement again.
>   To obtain this row count, include a
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the
>   SELECT statement, and then invoke
>   FOUND_ROWS() afterward:

so run the two following queries in PHP, the first statement gives the first 12 rows, the second one gives the total of rows:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  products.features
, products.make_id
, products.model
, products.price
, products.id
, brands.name AS brandname
, brands.id AS brandid
FROM products
LEFT JOIN brands ON products.make_id=brands.id
WHERE (products.active=1) AND (brands.active=1) AND (products.category=22)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,12"

$sql2 = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"
```

Comment: Cool but how does the MySQL server know for which query to return the number of rows if there are hundreds of queries per second on the server of the similar query from the same script?

Comment: It must be the very next query of the same connection. Same as for RowCount.

Answer (score 1):

This would return you the total number of rows the current select matches. The result will be one row, with one field and it will hold the `total`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM products
LEFT JOIN brands ON products.make_id=brands.id
WHERE products.active=1 AND brands.active=1 AND products.category=22
```

You will have to run this as a separate query.

```
<?php
$q=mysql_query('above query');
$result=mysql_fetch_array($q);
echo $result['total']; // will print out the desired number of rows
```

You were probably trying to get the total and the limit in the same select and while that might be possible with a union, but since you were worrying about inefficiency before, this is possible worse.

Since in your OP you hint that this is for pagination. Let me tell you, LIMIT m,n may not be as fast as it sounds. [Learn how to improve it](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=206034210932) and read more about [Efficient Pagination Using MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/suratbhati/efficient-pagination-using-mysql-6187107)

Comment: But the query can get a big bigger, likeselect products.features, products.make_id, products.model, products.price, products.contractprice, products.id, brands.name as brandname, brands.id as brandid from products left join brands on products.make_id=brands.id where products.active=1 and brands.active=1 and (make_id=2) and (formfactor_id=17) and (products.category=22) and (features like "%,32,%") and (features like "%,20,%") order by id desc limit 0,12

Comment: doesn't matter what you select, you ignore every item in the select and ignore the ORDER BY and the LIMIT, just to get the total number of rows, it will be faster than you expect

Comment: ok thanks I'll give it a try, see how many hundreds of queries per second it does now :)