# count all items in table mysql plus get record

Tags: php, mysql, count

Hi I have this situation:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*),* FROM memberFileReports');

$data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($data);
```

its not working ? any idea why and how to Count and get all items at the same time, and what if I want to Count (*) and then next Select will have Limit 0,5?

Comment: select count( * ) as total from table, is the correct way.. and you dont need to use COUNT( * ), *

Comment: I think you are looking for `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, this will give you the total rows even when using a limit.

Comment: if I use Select Count(*) I will get the COUNT ONLY , but I need to get the Count and loop through all the rows at the same time in one SQl statement

Comment: how could I use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS? could you show me an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT * , CONCAT('', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM memberFileReports)) AS total 
FROM memberFileReports LIMIT 0,5
```

EDIT 1: Note that the 'total' will be a string

EDIT 2: As I understand , you want to get the total rows in the table, but only select 5 of them (as example)

EDIT 3: caps... and misspell

Comment: yes I need to get total COUNT on the table but display only 5 of them

Comment: whats that extra "t" in : memberFileReportst limit

Comment: $query = $db->query('select * , CONCAT(", (select count(*) from memberFileReports)) as total from memberFileReports Limit 0 , 5');
   $data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '", (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM memberFileReports)) AS total FROM memberFileReports LIM' at line 1 )

Comment: I manged to make it work :

         $query = $db->query("SELECT * , CONCAT('', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM memberFileReports)) AS total FROM memberFileReports ORDER BY dateProcessed DESC LIMIT 0,2");
   $data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
   SELECT * , COUNT(*) FROM memberFileReports Group by column_id
```

Instead of this

```
   SELECT COUNT(*),* FROM memberFileReports
```

**EDIT:**

try this

```
   $data = $query->fetchAll();
```

instead of

```
  $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: With this I only get one Row?

Comment: @user3284909 Order matters, having `*` before `count(*) will work correctly, the opposite won't

Comment: its not working guys , I only get one Row result back

Comment: I did copy it , I don't get error but its not giving me what I want , I get back only 1 Row ?

Comment: $query = $db->query('SELECT * , COUNT(*) FROM memberFileReports');
 $data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
  print_r($data);

Comment: ok this updated should work , try my edited query. Note that you make your column_id

Comment: i see different rows but [COUNT(*)] => 1 ?

Comment: it will count for every id.

Comment: how do I get the total?

Comment: to get total you maybe need this `$data = $query->rowCount()`

Comment: yes I need to do rowCount() but how to limit this from 0,5 and still make the count work for ALL

Comment: use another query and get count all , and otherone with limit. and get 5 items

Comment: yes I am trying to make this in One Query I guess I can't :(

Comment: before doing it look this post have same question as yours maybe it help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596155/how-to-get-the-total-found-rows-without-considering-the-limit-in-pdo

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little late but i figured i would tell you, the reason why you only get one row back is because you are using an aggregate function "COUNT()". that function makes it so the result is returned in one row. the way to show stuff in more than one row is to use a "GROUP BY" in your select statement and it will group the data by the condition you tell it to.

example... suppose we had an example table with 3 users..

one has 10 interactions

one 3

and one 33:

`SELECT
   e.UserID,
   COUNT(e.interactions) as num_interactions
FROM example e
GROUP BY e.UserID;`

that would show the number of interactions a user has made in the dummy example table.

OUTPUT:

```
UserID     num_interactions

1           3

2           10

3           33
```

without the GROUP BY the aggregate would make the output look like this:

```
UserID     num_interactions

1           46
```

just for future reference :)